# C includes: where is last_component defined?

Tags: c, gnulib

See below logic from `wget` source code.  Where is `last_component` defined?  I presume this is either a GNU include or buried somewhere in the standard C includes.  But I can't seem to locate it.  Thx.

```
char *
get_metalink_basename (char *name)
{
  int n;
  char *basename;

  if (!name)
    return NULL;

  basename = last_component (name);

  while ((n = FILE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_LEN (basename)) > 0)
    basename += n;

  return metalink_check_safe_path (basename) ? basename : NULL;
}
```

Comment: did you try https://www.google.com/search?q=last_component+gnulib ?

Comment: did you?  if you find the source, please put it here and I'll be sure to credit you.  good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wget uses [gnulib](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/index.html). `last_component` is declared in [basename-lgpl.h](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob;f=lib/basename-lgpl.h#l33) and defined in [basename-lgpl.c](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob;f=lib/basename-lgpl.c#l30).